# How to sort a large file without using sort

Tags: python

So I was given the following prompt for homework at school:
[image]

Basically we were given a very large text file we needed to open and rewrite onto a new file but every line  had to be sorted by length (doesn't matter if decreasing or increasing length). I was able to come up with the following solution but my problem is that my run time is almost a minute since the file is so big. We cannot used sort and "the parts of this exercise should be done by making use of an implementation of the relevant interface (Stack, Queue, Deque, PriorityQueues, USet, or SSet) provided by Python".

```
def longest_string(originalFile, destinationFile):
    ogfile = open(originalFile, 'r')
    destfile = open(destinationFile, 'w')
    courses = ogfile.read()
    list = courses.split('\n')
    new_list = []

    while list:
        longest = list[0]
        for x in list:
            if (len(x)) > (len(longest)):
                longest = x
        list.remove(longest)
        new_list.append(longest)

     destfile.write('\n'.join(new_list))
```

I tried using priority queue but couldn't figure it out. Do I have to scrap my entire code and find another way? Or is there a way to improve my codes runtime? It has to be less than 3 seconds.

Comment: what is this usual sorted order, when length is same ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your question, can you rephrase? When length is the same the order is just whatever order it was read in from the original file if thats what you mean.

Comment: "the relevant interface (Stack, Queue, Deque, PriorityQueues, USet, or SSet)", where exactly are these interfaces defined? It appears these would have been provided to you in some library? Note that your sorting implementation is very inefficient, finding and removing each next element by traversing the entire list to find the longest element remaining, and then doing the whole thing over again. Both the search and selection and removal process are very inefficient and resulting in the poor performance you are seeing. Have a look at common sorting algorithms for something (a lot) faster

Comment: When you have to sort something that is too large to fit in memory, Merge Sort is the best option.  One nice thing about Merge Sort is that it can be made stable, so items which are equivalent in the sort will retain their original order.

Answer (score 0):

dont know file size limit, but you can following step to solve this problem.

1. use dictionary (ay `result ={}`to save the line as key and a list of length of line and index as value.
   ie  {line: [len_of_line, index]}
2. read the file line by line
3. for each line check if it is present in dictionary or not, if yes then ignore it and if no then save he line as key and for value add it's length and index to it ie

```
if line not in result:
            result[line] = [len(line), index]
```

4. once done, sort the result according to length and order as

```
 solution = sorted(result.items(), key = lambda x:[x[0],x[1]])
```

5. write each line in new file

```
for line, _ in solution:
           new_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a container from the list for this task and SSet means `sortedcontainers.SortedSet`, this is how you might use it:

```py
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
def sortByLengthLines(originalFile, destinationFile):
    with open(originalFile, 'r') as f:
        text = f.readlines()
    with open(destinationFile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join([i[30:] for i in SortedSet(map(lambda x: str(len(x)).zfill(30) + x, text))]))
```

I generated a random txt file with 10000 lines of the random length from 0 to 360 characters.
`%timeit` instruction in Jupyter Notebook tells me that this function takes 28 ms ± 869 µs to sort it (including SSD IO operations).
I measured the time your function takes for the same text file on my laptop, and `%timeit` output was 10 s ± 323 ms.